# JavaScript doesn't work on ICS

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-webview, epub

I am working on EPUB reader for the company using JavaScript, the application runs well on Android 2.2, but when i try it on ICS & HoneyCom, the JavaScript doesn't work well. The first problem i faced, the `WebView` doesn't load JS files (`Unknown Error -6`), so i used this solution:

```
@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d("shouldInterceptRequest", url);

    InputStream stream = inputStreamForAndroidResource(url);
    if (stream != null) {
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "utf-8", stream);
    }
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
}

private InputStream inputStreamForAndroidResource(String url) {
    final String ANDROID_ASSET = "file:///android_asset/";

    if (url.contains(ANDROID_ASSET)) {
        // url = url.replaceFirst(ANDROID_ASSET, "");
        String[] f = url.split("/");
        url = "epub/"
                + f[f.length - 1]
                        .substring(0, f[f.length - 1].indexOf("'"));
        try {
            AssetManager assets = mActivity.getAssets();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            return assets
                    .open(uri.getPath(), AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and now i don't have this error, but the JS still doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Hi, I'm now facing a similar problem with my WebView. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799880/google-code-prettify-js-not-working-in-ics-webview . You found any other solution for this problem ?

Comment: no i didn't, try the above solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only solution I found is the same as the question....

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stupid thing i'm saying here. But it's late and i'm tired ...

Have you tried enabling `Javascript` in the `WebView`?

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: its already enabled :), as i told you its working fine on 2.2 but the error is on ics & honeycomb, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

u can add one property android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in application tag of your manifest.xml as well u can add some settings in on create

```
wvMain.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
      wvMain.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      wvMain.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
      wvMain.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
      wvMain.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
      wvMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      wvMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
       wvMain.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
         wvMain.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);     

         wvMain.getSettings().setCacheMode(wvMain.getSettings().LOAD_NO_CACHE);
         webSettings8.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
         wvMain.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         wvMain.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
         wvMain.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
         wvMain.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
         wvMain.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
         wvMain.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

i hope this helps.but note, hardwareaccelerated property supports after 3.0.

Comment: most of what you said are enabled, but some of them like zoom and wideView i don't need, and still the same.

Comment: OK..well it don't happen generally. I suggest check your log cat. You will get to know on which line of your code the error is coming. May be it can be any null value or something.

Comment: There is one more option you can use broadcast receiver..I think this will definitely can help you