# JavaScript (stored inside assets) not working inside WebView in ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, prettify

> **Similar Problem :** 
>    [JavaScript doesn't work on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550756/javascript-doesnt-work-on-ics)

I'm working on an Android app that displays some code samples to the user. So, I'm using google-code-prettify in a WebView for syntax highlighting. But, the problem is, the js does not work on ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich) alone. It works **perfectly on all other Android versions** (2.2+) **except 4.0.x**. This is the code that I'm using.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewSample);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/code_snippets/sample_java.html");
```

---

> The only error-like message that I get from logcat is **UNKNOWN CHROMIUM**
>   **ERROR: -6**

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any error message, exception trace, or other artifact that would let someone who doesn't have a device running 4.0.x and access to sample_java.html debug the problem?

Comment: @MikeSamuel The only _error-like_ message that i get from logcat is **UNKNOWN CHROMIUM ERROR: -6**

Comment: I maintain prettify so I'd love to know the answer to your problem, but I have no way to try and replicate the problem, especially not without your code.  [This search](https://www.google.com/search?q="UNKNOWN+CHROMIUM+ERROR%3A+-6") might point you at some similar code.

Comment: @MikeSamuel UPDATE: It works properly when I call the prettify js from the internet. The problem arises only when I call a local file.

Comment: from what i have seen, UNKNOWN CHROMIUM *ERROR: -6* means the requested resource is not found. you can try to narrow it down by logging the url `shouldInterceptRequest` and looking which is the last called before the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't find any proper solution.. So, I ended up following [MoshErsan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737925/moshersan)'s suggestion as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550756/javascript-doesnt-work-on-ics):

This is what I did:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);       
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("shouldInterceptRequest", url);
        InputStream stream = inputStreamForAndroidResource(url);
        if (stream != null) {
            return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "utf-8", stream);
        }
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }
    private InputStream inputStreamForAndroidResource(String url) {
        final String ANDROID_ASSET = "file:///android_asset/";
        if (url.contains(ANDROID_ASSET)) {
            url = url.replaceFirst(ANDROID_ASSET, "");
            try {
                AssetManager assets = getAssets();
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                return assets.open(uri.getPath(), AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }           
});
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/code_snippets/sample_java.html");
```

Don't know what the actual problem is. But, this hack works.